# Context memory leaks in android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have read on the developers blog about Context memory leaks.

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

But Im not sure that I have understand it.

Does the method `getAppVersion` will cause memory leaks because of the context reference?

```
public class A
{

public static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

}

public class B extends Activity
{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);

       int version = A.getAppVersion(this);

}

}
```

Comment: No the memory leak could happen if you save an Activity-context in a static field. In your case you don't do that.

Comment: And the `getAppVersion` only holds the reference to the `context` while the method is being executed. Afterwards it's removed and doesn't "live" anymore.

Comment: Just avoid holding any Android components bound to a Context OUTSIDE of the Context itself. You have to understand that almost anything in Android is managed, so don't make any assumptions about anything you're not 100% sure of. The rule of thumb is basically that you stay inside Android's life cycles and match the scope of your own variables with them.

Answer (score 0):

What about context memory leaks - agree with what was said before, and here is what helps me to avoid them in the application:

- Avoid using static variables for views or context-related references.
- Pass a context-related reference to a Singleton class.
- Use applicationContext() instead of activity context or view context when it’s possible. For example, for Toasts, Snackbars.
- Use a weak reference of the context-related references when needed.

Here is some more details on these cases https://www.symphony-solutions.eu/fixing-memory-leaks-in-android/